# Transfers to user's bank account

Tags: paypal, account, bank

On paypal, it is possible for a user to purchase services on a site by bank card or by paypal account. 
But is it possible for the site to make transfers automatically to a user's bank account? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is nothing related to programming!!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.  Your only option is to send money to somebody's PayPal account, and then they can transfer to their bank.

Comment: Any solution to do that ?

Comment: You would need a merchant account that provides ACH payments.